# Official API for grabbing app version on Google PlayStore

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I know Apple has this API I can hit:

`http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId={id}`

However, for the PlayStore, I'm looking for something similar, rather than parsing the app page

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={id}`

and then looking for the `<div>` that contains `itemprop="softwareVersion"`

There are a few questions about this here on SO and elsewhere on the web, but they are outdated, and make reference to unofficial APIs.

Comment: What you call "outdated" is the current state :(

Answer (score 3):

There is no Official API for grabbing the App version from the Play store.

I'd be curious exactly what you would use such an API for, if you wanted to add it in a comment. There may be a better way of achieving what you want.

Edit:
For forcing an update to your app there are other recommendations. We normally recommend that you don't have "always update to the latest version in the Play store" to developers. For example, the user might want to use your app, but be in a place where they don't have much battery or wifi. Forcing them to update in such a situation is rude, it's much better  to give them a week or two until a more convenient time.

If you want to do "never have a version that is more than a couple of weeks old", can I recommend [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/). This would let you on the server update a configuration options for your app saying "the user should have at least this version" and change the behaviour of your app accordingly. It is much more flexible at robust than polling the Play store.

Comment: It was for comparing current version/state of app to what is currently available in the app store and then suggesting or forcing the user to update the app.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to give my recommendation for this situation.

Comment: +1 for Remote Config, I use it for the exact scenario. I put the latest app version in firebase and the app checks it to see if there is an update that is needed

Comment: Add me to the list of people who would like an API like this. I'm designing a similar feature in my app and because the Play store can delay app releases depending on the region how else am I supposed to know if a release is actually "gettable" for a user?

Comment: @NickFortescue Does the remote config method require manual input?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be the **Support In-app updates** besides *Firebase Remote config*.

**Google** has released the *Support In-app updates* feature in which the apps can nudge the users to update their apps without even going to the play store. If an update is available, the users will see a *dialog* or a *full blocking screen* where the UI is generated and controlled by google play.

In-app updates works only with devices running `Android 5.0 (API level 21)` or higher, and requires you to use Play Core library 1.5.0 or higher. After meeting these requirements, your app can support the following UX for in-app updates!

references are [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates) and this helpful [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/android-in-app-updates-common-pitfalls-and-some-good-patterns-9024988bbbe8). Check this out, hope it will help.